# Conditional count sequence in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

| ID# | Days Since Activity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 9 |

And I want to include a "count" column that counts all entries and resets when the ID# changes **OR** if the "Days Since Activity" is 10 or greater. An example output is as follows:

| ID# | Days Since Activity | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 9 | 3 |

I tried doing the following code:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(`ID#`) %>%
  mutate(`Count` = seq(n()))
```

But that only reset the count when the ID# changed. How can I incorporate both criteria into my count? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

We can create logical flags every time the ID changes or the days since activity exceed 10 (plus special handling for the first row), accumulate these as a cumulative sum, and then use that as a grouping variable to create the numbering.

I've left the extra columns in the final output for the purposes of illustration.

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 3)),
  days = c(1, 5, 5, 10, 3, 4, 2, 9)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    id_change = replace_na(id != lag(id), TRUE),
    days_exceeded = days >= 10,
    group = cumsum(id_change | days_exceeded)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(count = row_number())

     id  days id_change days_exceeded group count
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>     <lgl>         <int> <int>
1     1     1 TRUE      FALSE             1     1
2     1     5 FALSE     FALSE             1     2
3     1     5 FALSE     FALSE             1     3
4     1    10 FALSE     TRUE              2     1
5     1     3 FALSE     FALSE             2     2
6     2     4 TRUE      FALSE             3     1
7     2     2 FALSE     FALSE             3     2
8     2     9 FALSE     FALSE             3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, count = cumsum(days>=10)) %>%
  mutate(count = row_number())

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id, count [6]
     id  days count
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     1
2     1     5     2
3     1     5     3
4     1    10     1
5     1     3     2
6     2     4     1
7     2     2     2
8     2     9     3
```